# How to redirect skipping subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I am on `abc.domainname.com`

Now in any action

I want to redirect to a page `domainname.com` without subdomain.

How can I do this?

I tried like `index_path(:subdomain => false)`.

If I hardcode like `redirect_to("http://domainname.com")`. Then it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did in this way,

`index_url(:subdomain => false)`

And it works!